# Pass parameter to create action in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, routes

I am having issues getting the page to render when using a parameter in a create controller. My show controller works but my create controller doesn't. The error thrown is a 404.

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

The URL is:
`http://myapp.test/country/us/state/create`

My controller looks like:

```php
// Show
public function show(Country $country, State $state){
  return view('state.show', compact('state'));
}
// Create
public function create(Country $country) {
  return view('state.create', compact('country'));
}
```

My route looks like:

```
Route::get('country/{country}/state/{state}', 'StateController@show');
Route::get('country/{country}/state/create', 'StateController@create');
```

Comment: Please show how do you generate the link that shows 404.

Comment: The URL is: `http://myapp.test/country/us/state/create` 
just edited the post also

Comment: The create route should have precedence before the state route

Comment: @DaveyContreras thanks. As linktoahref said, put the `create` route before the first route.

Comment: Thanks you guys, That fixed the issue!!! and waoo... little things like that would have you pull your hairs... why does that even matter?

Comment: The `{state}` route was first in hierarchy, and it would accept any variable in place of `{state}` hence the respective route got invoked, but failed to resolve the State using `create` hence thrown 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flip your routes around to be

```
Route::get('country/{country}/state/create', 'StateController@create');
Route::get('country/{country}/state/{state}', 'StateController@show');
```

Laravel processes routes in the order that they are defined, so in your current code Laravel was seeing `create` as a `state`.